# Uniform Artin-Rees bound for annihilators in Noetherian local rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring. If $I$ is an ideal of $A$, then by (a weak version of) the Artin-Rees lemma, there exists $j \geq 0$ such that for all $i \geq j$,
$$\mathfrak{m}^i \cap I \subseteq \mathfrak{m}^{i-j} I.$$

**Question:** Can we choose $j$ such that the above inclusion holds with $I = \mathrm{Ann}_A(a)$ for all $a \in A$?

Comment: Do you mean "Can we choose $j$ such that..."?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I fixed the typo in the question.